# Multiline Comment Parsing Bug

Tags: alloy

Working with the latest Alloy analyzer currently available at the website (4.2 Build date: 2012-09-25) I realized that, when I put code between two `/**/` like this `/**/ <some code> /**/`, the code `<some code>` seems to be ignored by the analyzer (although the editor seems to parse the code correctly).

For example, in the following code snippet the declaration of the `fact` is ignored by the analyzer:

```
/**/
fact traces {
    init [first]
    all d: Dinner - last | 
        let d' = next [d] | 
            some p,p': Philosopher, f: Fork | 
                pickLeftFork [d,d',p,p',f]
}
/**/
```

As soon as I put a space between `/**/`, that is, `/* */`, the code behaves as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java-style doc comments have been recently added to Alloy, so in your example above, the `/**` token at the beginning starts a doc comment, and the `**/` token at the very end closes is, so everything in between is parsed as a comment.

Comment: For the record - at which version was this comment form added?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, the editor doesn't indicate this kind of comment (at least not at the time of this writing).

Comment: You are right, that should be fixed.  The reason this was added was the Alloy plugin for Eclipse (http://code.google.com/p/alloy4eclipse/), which presumably does something different with such doc comments.